# How to use TextRange to replace letters of a Run?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, flowdocument

I am completely new to FlowDocuments and can't seem to find this anywhere.

I created a TextBlock where each Inline is a Run containing exactly one word. (The Inlines are created in code). I then use TextRange to replace some letters within the Run. But instead of replacing the characters of the Run, ***the TextRange seems to empty the Run and append the letters to the previous Run.***

(It is important to retain the original TextBlock structure with the original Run objects as I have events tied to them.)

What am I doing wrong? And what is the TextRange.Text = text actually doing?

Any help is appreciated.

Example

```
  ---Before textrange--
<Run>
6||perrla
</Run>
<Run>
1||                       **NOTE THIS IS A SPACE IN THE RUN
</Run>
<Run>
5||nc/at
</Run>

--After textrange --- 
<Run>           **NOTE THE EMPTY RUN
</Run>
<Run>
5|| test    **NOTE HOW TEST IS APPENDED TO THE SPACE OF THE PREVIOUS RUN
</Run>
<Run>
5||nc/at
</Run>
```

The code that produce the above results:

```
            string text = nw.Replace("\0", string.Empty);

            TextPointer s = StartInlineElement.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            TextPointer start = s.GetPositionAtOffset(StartIndex);
            TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(Text.Length);

            var y = start.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Backward);
            if (y != null)
            {
                do
                {
                    GetXaml((TextElement)y);
                    y = (y as Run).PreviousInline;
                } while (y != null);
            }

            THIS IS WRONG -- IT EMPTIES THE RUN AND APPENDS TO THE RUN
            BEFORE IT.
            TextRange tr = new TextRange(start, end);
            tr.Text = text;

            y = start.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (y != null)
            {
                do
                {
                    GetXaml((TextElement)y);
                    y = (y as Run).PreviousInline;
                } while (y != null);
            }
        }
```

GetXaml is from Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointercontext(v=vs.110).aspx)  which I slighltly modified to:

```
     void GetXaml(TextElement element)
    {
        // Position a "navigator" pointer before the opening tag of the element.
        TextPointer navigator = element.ElementStart;

        while (navigator.CompareTo(element.ElementEnd) < 0)
        {
            switch (navigator.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward))
            {
                case TextPointerContext.ElementStart:
                    // Output opening tag of a TextElement
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("<{0}>", navigator.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward).GetType().Name));
                    break;
                case TextPointerContext.ElementEnd:
                    // Output closing tag of a TextElement
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("</{0}>", navigator.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward).GetType().Name));
                    break;
                case TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement:
                    // Output simple tag for embedded element
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("<{0}>", navigator.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward).GetType().Name));
                    break;
                case TextPointerContext.Text:
                    // Output the text content of this text run
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}||{1}", navigator.GetTextRunLength(LogicalDirection.Forward),
                        navigator.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward)));
                    break;
            }

            // Advance the naviagtor to the next context position.
            navigator = navigator.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is caused because TextRange.Start will always have a LogicalDirection or Backward. So it puts the text in the previous element.

Maybe my fix for my particular situation can help you fix your own problem:

```
if (this.Selection.Start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Backward) == TextPointerContext.ElementStart &&
    this.Selection.End.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.ElementEnd &&
    this.Selection.Start.Parent == this.Selection.End.Parent && this.Selection.Start.Parent is Run)
{
     ((Run)this.Selection.Start.Parent).Text = "NewText";
}
```